# This is possible to using bash script for User Authentication Banner in SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to ask something.

I make user for Linux, and there create User Authentication Banner (If you use Bitvise, you will know). I tried to use bash script.

This is /etc/mybanner

```
#!/bin/bash
MYIP=`wget icanhazip.com -qO -`
echo -e "Selamat datang, berikut informasi akun anda:"
echo -e "IP: $MYIP"
```

In my dropbear config

```
OPTIONS="-p 22 -b /etc/mybanner"
```

I try to login and see, but I get it in my banner:

[image: This is my get]

So, this is possible to use banner using shell script ?

Thanks

Comment: You must use motd

Comment: motd can use bash ?

Comment: The only time your IP address can change will be when a network interface goes up, so you could add a script to your `network-manager` configuration (or what have you) to update a static banner file whenever the network topology changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your customized bash script in `motd`. Actually, the contents of /etc/motd are displayed after a successful login but just before it executes the login shell.

You can read about `motd` on [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/motd) and also you can read  [CUSTOMIZE YOUR MOTD](http://www.mewbies.com/how_to_customize_your_console_login_message_tutorial.htm) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that MOTD is the standard way to go

I wrote this guide to generate dynamic (or static) logins.

Basically you have to put scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/` or modify `/var/run/motd.dynamic` from cron or `/etc/init.d`

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/